# Always source bashrc in AlmaLinux / RedHat based system

Tags: bash, alma-linux

I have an infrastructure that mostly consists of Ubuntu machines and many users. We like to use X2GO for remote access, which works well. We now have an AlmaLinux 8.8 machine. When login onto that one with X2GO and opening a terminal, the prompt is messed up and only writes something like `bash-4.4$` .
We figured out that this is because opening a terminal in X2GO is not a login shell (sorry, not so sure anymore, see edit) <strike>and thus the `/etc/bashrc` is not sourced by the `/etc/profile`</strike>. The Ubuntu system is somehow configured to work without a local `.bashrc` in the user's home directory.
Thus, all home dirs are created without a `.bashrc`.

I want to fix that on the AlmaLinux machine by always sourcing the `/etc/bashrc`. This is because I do not have access to the mechanism that creates new homes for new users, and I do not want to create/tell all users to have a local `.bashrc`. Is there a way to realize that? I do have sudo rights on the Alma machine.

[Edit]
After checking again, I noticed this block in the `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ -n "${BASH_VERSION-}" ] ; then
        if [ -f /etc/bashrc ] ; then
                # Bash login shells run only /etc/profile
                # Bash non-login shells run only /etc/bashrc
                # Check for double sourcing is done in /etc/bashrc.
                . /etc/bashrc
       fi
fi
```

Comment: Can you edit the `/etc/profile` on the relevant machines? If you can just add `. /etc/bashrc` as an additional line in `/etc/profile`. But why not just add what you need from `/etc/bashrc` to `/etc/profile`?

Comment: @Uberhumus: OP says their issue is that a non-login shell is being started – and non-login shells do not load /etc/profile, which seemingly is the very problem here.

Comment: @u1686_grawity, I suspect one of us is reading it wrong. "We figured out the that is because opening a terminal in X2GO is not a login shell and thus the /etc/bashrc is not sourced by the /etc/profile" hints that `/etc/profile` is loaded. He specifically asks: "I would like to fix that on the AlmaLinux machine by always sourcing the /etc/bashrc.". Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you edit `/etc/profile`? That requires root access. If you have root access, you also have write access to `/etc/skel/` so you can set up new users with  `.bashrc` if you want to.

Comment: I have root access to the machines. Home directories are created by the IT central service and therefore I have no control over the home creation process.

Answer (score 1):

Your explanation is a bit off. Login shells do read the `profile` family of files, but they don't read the `bashrc` ones; it's non-login shells that don't read `profile` but do read `bashrc`. As for Ubuntu, yes, it may be set up to not have local `.bashrc`, presumably by not having one at `/etc/skel`. You could add a default file there which should then be copied for all new users.

As for having your login shells read `bashrc`, I would personally suggest having the settings you need in `/etc/profile` instead, but if you don't want that, you can make `/etc/profile` source `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Just add this to your `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
  if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bash.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

This will source `/etc/bash.bashrc` if the shell reading `/etc/profile` is bash and is not bash as `/bin/sh` (bash in POSIX mode). A few Linux distributions do this by default, as far as I know only those in the Debian family, but maybe others as well. Note that this assumes your `/etc/bash.bashrc` has code to exit if the shell is not interactive. On my Arch, this looks like:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[[ $- != *i* ]] && return
```

If you don't have a similar line in your `/etc/bash.bashrc`, add one so that you do not read it for non-interactive shells where you realy don't want the settings in bashrc to be active.

Comment: I have added the proposed code to ```/etc/profile``` but it does not fix the problem. Most likey due to the edit I put in the question. Sorry for putting the situation wrongly.

Comment: @SimonT. but that means you _are_ reading `/etc/bash.bashrc` from login shells. But if you are opening a GUI terminal, that isn't a login shell, no. However, that should read `/etc/bash.bashrc` by default as well.  But what is this `/etc/bashrc` file you mention? That isn't standard, the standard file is `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Is that a typo? Also, if you have root access, why don't you just create a default `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file so that all new users have the setup you want?

Comment: On AlmaLinux I don't see a ```/etc/bash.bashrc``` I only have the ```/etc/bashrc```. No ```bash.``` before. The homes are created on a NFS, and I guess for new user they will be initialized by the first machine they log into. This can now be either a Ubuntu or this single AlmaLinux machine. I would have to force the users to log in to the Alma machine first, right? That may sound picky, but that is also not a preferred solution for me.

Comment: No, I get that. But you can just create an `/etc/skel/.bashrc` file on each machine, and then any new accounts will have that file copied to their `$HOME` no matter where they log in. As for the rest, is the `/etc/bashrc` the file you want then? Does it have the settings you expect?

Comment: Ok, let me understand. Is the skeleton checked every time? So when I place a .bashrc there, it will be copied to every user's home that logs in and misses that file? I will try that. Yes the ```/etc/bashrc```does the correct thing. I tested by having a local .bashrc in my home that sources the /etc one.

Comment: I checked, the ```/etc/skel``` already has a ```.bashrc``` that also does the correct thing. However, it is not automatically copied to my home directory.

Comment: Hmm. That's odd. Maybe it wasn't there when your user was created? Is your default shell configured to be bash? Anyway, the files in `/etc/skel` are copied only when users are created and only if they are created with `useradd -m` to create their home. See `man useradd` for more details. So no, they aren't checked every time.

Comment: The user creation does not happen on my machines they are created by a centralized service, therefore I do not have any control over what goes in there.